# settimeout executes multiple times

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

On button click I am calling Ajax function after every 3min

```
intervalId = setTimeout(function(){ searchSiteDetailViaAjax() }, 180000);
```

and on stop button I am stopping this

```
clearTimeout(intervalId);
intervalId = null;
```

initially for few time it works fine but then after executing the clearTimeout the timer calls the Ajax function again and again.

Comment: Not enough information here. What scope are you defining `intervalId` in? Add more code.

Comment: Can you post more information? Code sample?

Comment: Scope of the intervalId is global.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to be working with `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`. `setTimeout()` only runs once, and you said you'd like it to run every 3 minutes, and you'll want to use `setInterval()` for that.

setInterval MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

clearInterval MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may need to call `clearTimeout(intervalId);` on click, prior to your `setTimeout` call.

It sounds like what is happening is that you queue a function to be executed and by clicking the button again you queue another execution and receive a different handle.  Clicking the stop button will not longer be able to clear the previous handles which causes your multiple executions.

Comment: Well don't forget to give me my props! haha. Glad I could help